# How to apply special characters in string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose we have the following string object:

```
var str = "Real\bWorl\bd";
```

considering \b as BackSpace character, I want a mechanism to get

```
ReaWord
```

as result, this means BackSpace character some how compiled within the string.
aside from BackSpace, this special character might be Delete.
Thanks in advance....

Comment: We won't write that code for you. Can you post your attempts at solving this problem?

Comment: Imo you should use a regex to do this.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi sure.

Comment: @StrandedKid well, I think regex wont cover this issue, unless you have a brilliant idea.

Comment: @Khodabakhsh https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/replace ??? Pass a regex with all the characters you want to be removed, then replace them by an empty string. Nothing brilliant in it, just common sense.

Comment: @StrandedKid Thanks for that, but the intention of the question is to apply backspace character in string, not removing that.

Comment: @Khodabakhsh that means that in your example, the letter "l" should have been deleted by the backspace, but instead get encoded... How is that even possible to happen :D

Comment: @Khodabakhsh If you use server side lanaguage like C# you will get your desire result. In JavaScript jquery a custom logic or regex is required.

Comment: @MuhammadDanish unfortunately what I need is exactly the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function formatStr(str){
  if(str.indexOf("\b")!=-1){
      
      return formatStr(str.substring(0, str.indexOf("\b")-1) + 
                       str.substring(str.indexOf("\b")+1, str.length));
    
  }
  else return str;
}

var str = "Real\bWor\bld";
alert(formatStr(str));
```

Comment: Nice, But it doesn't covering all the Backspace occurrences, while I have mentioned that Delete key is also considered.

Comment: @Khodabakhsh it covers all the backspace occurences. And what exactly you mean by delete key?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function replaceBackslash(str)
{ 
  return str.split(/[a-z]\b/).join("")+ str.charAt(str.length -1);
}

replaceBackslash( "Real\bWorld\bddd" );
replaceBackslash( "Real\bWorld" );
```

Comment: Works fine for backspace, but how about delete?

Comment: @Khodabakhsh how would you manage to put a 'delete' character in your string?

Comment: @Khodabakhsh for me backspace is assimilated to a delete action, I don't think you meant backspace, more like chariot return?

Comment: [this.value.slice(0, cursor), String.fromCharCode(keycode), this.value.slice(cursor)].join('');

Comment: the keycode is the key being pressed and passed to keyup event, I want to put that key at position cursor in a string.

Comment: @Khodabakhsh share the resulting string as well. Even better, add it to your question.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Unfortunately not.

Comment: @Khodabakhsh can you try to run a string `"Real\bWorld\bddd"` in your console? You most likely won't get any character like \b `back`.

Answer (score -2):

Check this

```
function removeBackspaces()
{

var str = "Real\bWorl\bd";

var word = "";

  for(var i=0; i < str.length; i++)
  {

    if(str[i] != '\b')
    {
      word += str[i]

    }
    else
    {
      //var lastIndex = word.lastIndexOf(" ");
       word = word.substring(0, word.length-1);

    }

  }
   return word;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

use following code

> unescape(str)

Comment: `unescape` is a deprecated (so you shouldn't use it at all) function to convert **hexadecimal** escapes (which ``\b`` is not) back to real characters, so this won't work.